# Mysql using SELECT CONCAT results as a condition in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, concatenation

I'm trying to use this query where I need to concatenate a string before compare to obtain the right results. The query is running, but is not finding any results. I believe the problem is when I try to compare "myname" in the `WHERE` clause. Any idea on what's the right query for this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT CONCAT('tm_',name) AS myname FROM room) room, users
WHERE user_name = myname;
```

Comment: You can always use `HAVING` clause to constrain aggregated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

```
SELECT * FROM users,room where user_name=concat('tm_',name);
```

?

Comment: So simple, so obvious... but I was trying to complicate the path :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
   SELECT CONCAT('tm_',name) AS myname 
   FROM room
) t
WHERE user_name = myname
```

May be you need to `JOIN` the other table `users` like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
   SELECT CONCAT('tm_',name) AS myname 
   FROM room
) t
INNER JOIN users u ON ... --some join condition
WHERE user_name = myname
```

**Or:**

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
   SELECT CONCAT('tm_',name) AS myname 
   FROM room
) t, users
WHERE t.user_name = myname"
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion, it keeps returning no results. I still bet it's myname on WHERE clause the guilty. Fortunately we got the solution.